# ¿Como puedo obtener el color de fondo de mi pagina a travez de la consola?

Tags: javascript, css, web

Quisiera saber como puedo obtener el fondo de color de mi web por medio de la consola, teniendo por ejemplo la siguiente pagina:

```css
body{
 background-color: #FFCC66;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title> Pagina </title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

intente con lo siguiente

```
document.body.style.getPropertyValue("background-color");
```

pero su salida fue ***""***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a la respuesta de [Teemu de SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu)

Lo puedes lograr con el uso del método `getComputedStyle()` del cual puedes consultar mas aquí: [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Del modo siguiente:

```
let color = window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null).getPropertyValue('background-color');
console.log(color)
```

> Lo que hace este método es regresar un objeto, desde el cual puedes acceder a todos las propiedades CSS del elemento en cuestión

**Referencias:**

- [Respuesta original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588801/document-body-style-backgroundcolor-is-undefined/17589043)